# NSDictionary inspect in debug

Tags: xcode, debugging, nsdictionary, watch

I wish look inside my NSDictionary during my debug operation...what is the fastest and best way to do this?? xcode doesn't have a watch like visual studio to look the objects?

[alt text http://www.ghiboz.info/shots/f1320fc6.png](http://www.ghiboz.info/shots/f1320fc6.png)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can open debugger (CMD+SHIFT+Y) select your dictionary instance, right click on it and choose "Print description in console". Then open run log (CMD+SHIFT+R) and you'll see the contents of your dictionary. Isn't so good as in VS, but I haven't find another way yet. 
[Screenshot](http://nimblekit.com/ad/sc2.png)

Answer (score 0):

XCode 4.6 has added the following functionality which may be helpful to you

```
The elements of NSArray and NSDictionary objects can now be inspected in the Xcode debugger
```

Now you can inspect these object types without having to print the entire object in the console. Enjoy!

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_6.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to switch to your console view and type "po myDictionary".  The dictionary will be printed in NSLog format.

("po" is for "print object".  To print a scalar value do "p someScalar".  Printing `myDictionary.count` is a little trickier:  `p (int) [myDictionary count]`.)